# Sum of independent random variables is also independent

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given that $X, Y$ and $Z$ are discrete independent random variables,
how can one show that $X+Y$ and $Z$ are independent as well?

---

So far, I tried using the definition of independent variables and simplifying (X+Y)'s probability function using discrete convolution. I'm not sure that's the best way though.

Comment: Using the definition of independent variables and simplifying (X+Y)'s probability function using discrete convolution.
I'm not sure that's the best way though.

Comment: Events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $\mathbb P(A|B) = \mathbb P(A)$ and $\mathbb P(B|A) = \mathbb P(B)$, provided they have non-zero probabilities

Comment: @DanRobertson Far from the most convenient definition here.

Comment: Let $W=X+Y$. Use the fact that $\Pr(W=w)$ is the sum of all terms of the shape $\Pr((X=x_i)\cap (Y=y_j))$ where $x_i+y_j=w$.

Comment: Both the answers contradict this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222242/is-the-sum-of-two-variables-independent-of-a-third-variable-if-they-are-so-on-t

Comment: @user633741 This has that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are all independent, (meaning that $\Pr(X = x, Y = y, Z = z) = \Pr(X = x)\Pr(Y = y)\Pr(Z = z)$ for all $x, y, z$) the thing you linked has that $X$ is independent of $Y$ (only giving $\Pr(X = x, Y = y) = \Pr(X = x)\Pr(Y = y)$) and $X$ is independent of $Z$. (only giving $\Pr(X = x, Z = z) = \Pr(X = x)\Pr(Z = z)$) The latter two conditions do not imply the former, indeed there's not much reason to think they should, when written out.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: The adding $X+Y$ is not necessarily important. It suffices to show $P((X,Y)|Z) = P(X,Y)$ and $P(Z|(X,Y)) = P(Z)$ (why?). So no need for convolutions. Note this original claim might not hold under just pairwise independence assumptions on $X,Y,Z$, but you said "independent" which is stronger and should suffice to show $(X,Y)$ is independent of $Z$.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{align} 
f_{X+Y,Z}(s,t) & = f_{X+Y}(s\mid t)f_Z(t)
\\ & = f_Z(t)\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y\mid Z}(x,s-x\mid t)\operatorname d s 
\\ & \mathop{=}^{?} f_Z(t)\int_\Bbb R f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid t)f_{Y\mid Z}(s-x\mid t)\operatorname d s \tag{$\bigstar$}
\\ & = f_Z(t)\int_\Bbb R f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(s-x)\operatorname d s 
\\ & = f_Z(t) \int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x,s-x)\operatorname d x
\\ & = f_Z(t)f_{X+Y}(s)
\end{align}$

$\star$ This is *only* true iff we have **conditional independence** ; $X\perp Y\mid Z$.  This is *not necessarily* the case. Independence does not guarantee that conditional independence will also hold.

Answer (score 0):

> Two discrete random variables $X,Y$ are independent *iff* for all $x\in X(\Omega)$ and $y\in Y(\Omega)$ we have $P(X=x, Y=y)=P(X=x)\cdot P(Y=y)$. (Here $\Omega$ denotes the discrete sample space)

We choose two arbitrary but fixed elements $u_0\in(X+Y)(\Omega)$ and $z_0\in Z(\omega)$. Then, we consider

\begin{align*}
&P((X+Y)=u_0,Z=z_0)\\
&=\sum\limits_{x\in X(\Omega), y\in Y(\Omega)\\\text{with }x+y=u_0}P(X=x, Y=y,Z=z_0)\\
&=\sum\limits_{x\in X(\Omega), y\in Y(\Omega)\\\text{with }x+y=u_0}P(X=x)\cdot P( Y=y)\cdot P(Z=z_0)=P(Z=z_0)\cdot \sum\limits_{x\in X(\Omega), y\in Y(\Omega)\\\text{with }x+y=u_0}P(X=x)\cdot P( Y=y)\\
&=P(Z=z_0)\cdot P((X+Y)=u_0).
\end{align*}
We have used the independence of $X,Y,Z$ at the second equal sign.

As $u_0$ and $z_0$ were chosen arbitrarily, $(X+Y)$ and $Z$ are independent.