# The distribution of the sum of three random variables

Tags: probability, bivariate-distributions

Consider three rv, X, Y, Z with joint Gaussian distribution. Namely, the first two
are a bivariate Gaussian vector, with non zero correlation ρ(x,y) , while Z is independent from the first two. Denoting as usual with µx, µy , µz the means, find the
distribution of the sum
X + Y + Z

clearly indicating all the properties you use

My doubt is can I calculate the distribution of X+Y, and then do the convolution between Z and what I obtained before?

Comment: I'm looking into it, but it seems like you can't simply take the convolution between $Z$ and $X+Y$ since you can't guarantee those two variables are independent. According to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308348/sum-of-independent-random-variables-is-also-independent Even if $X$ and $Y$ were independent that still wouldn't be enough to guarantee $X+Y$ and $Z$ to be independent.

Comment: you can substitute $X'=X+Z$ which will be normal variable but you would have to recompute matrix $\Sigma$ and $\mu_{X'} = \mu_X + \mu_Z$ and then compute $X'+Y$

Comment: If $Z$ is independent from pair $(X,Y)$, then $Z$ is independent from $X+Y$.

Comment: Sorry, from the test of the exercise how do you assume that Z is independent from the pair and not from the singular X and singular Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if $\ Z\ $ is independent of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $, then $\ X+Y\ $ and $\ Z\ $ are independent, so you can compute the distribution of $\ X+Y+Z\ $ by convolving the distributions of $\ X+Y\ $ and $\ Z\ $.

There's really no need to do that, however, since $\ X+Y+Z\ $ must be normal with mean $\ \mu_X+\mu_Y+\mu_Z\ $ and variance
$\ 
\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2+\sigma_Z^2+$$2\sigma_X\sigma_Y\rho_{XY}\ 
$, where $\ \sigma_X, \sigma_Y\ $ and $\  \sigma_Z\ $ are the standard deviations of $\ X,Y\ $ and $\ Z\ $, respectively.

Comment: Thank you! Therefore, if i understand, in my case in which ρxy is equal zero the sum X+Y+Z will be a normal with mean μx+μy+μz and variance σ^2x+σ^2y+σ^2z?

Comment: Yes. If $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $ are uncorrelated and  follow a bivariate Gaussian distribution, then they're independent.  But in your original question you say they're bivariate Gaussian with *non-zero* correlation.  Was that a typo?  Also, more generally, if $\ X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n\ $ are multivariate Gaussian with means $\ \mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_n\ $, and covariance matrix $\ \Sigma\ $, and $\ A\ $ an $\ m\times n\ $ matrix, then the entries of $\ AX\ $ are multivariate Gaussian with mean $\ A\mu\ $, and covariance matrix $\ A^\top\Sigma A\ $.

Comment: Yes sorry you are right! the correlation it isn't zero

Comment: Sorry having Z independent from X and Y it doesn't mean that X+Y is independent from Z. How can I prove that in my case

Comment: If the distribution of $\ X,Y,Z\ $ is *joint Gaussian*, then so is the distribution of $\ X+Y, Z\ $, and all you need for the independence of $\ X+Y\ $ and $\ Z\ $ in that case is that they are uncorrelated.  This follows from the fact that both $\ X\ $ and $\ Z\ $ and $\ Y\ $ and $\ Z\ $ are uncorrelated.

Comment: Perfect I have understand!! Thank you for all!!