# Independence of sum of i.i.d. random variables from remaining variables

Tags: probability-theory, convolution, independence

The following question is very similar to [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308348/sum-of-independent-random-variables-is-also-independent).

Let $(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})$ be a random vector with continuous independent variable entries. We denote by $X_{1}^{1}, X_{1}^{2}$ two variables that are i.i.d. as $X_{1}$

Claim: $(X_{1}^{1}+ X_{1}^{2},X_{2}, X_{3})$ are again independent.

I would required this for a sum of $n$ i.i.d. variables, which would follow by induction.

Proposed proof:

Let $Z := X_{1}^{1}+ X_{1}^{2}$ and $Y := (X_{2}, X_{3})$.

In similar fashion to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308348/sum-of-independent-random-variables-is-also-independent) we repeat the application of the convolution formula

\begin{equation}
f_{z, y}(z, y) =f_{z \mid y}(z \mid y) \cdot f_{y}(y) 
=f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_0^{z-x_1^2} f_z\left(x_1^1, x_1^2 \mid y\right) d x_1^1 d x_1^2 = f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_z\left(z-x_1^2, x_1^2|y\right)  d x_1^2
\end{equation}

Here comes a step, where one requires that $X_{1}^{1}|Y$ is independent from $X_{1}^{2}| Y$. I am not certain whether this is actually satisfied

\begin{equation}
f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_z\left(z-x_1^2, x_1^2|y\right)  d x_1^2 = f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{x_{1}^{1}} (z-x_1^2|y) f_{x_{1}^{1}} (x_1^2|y) d x_1^2 =f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{x_{1}^{1}} (z-x_1^2) f_{x_{1}^{1}} (x_1^2) d x_1^2 = f_{y} (y) f_{z} (z)
\end{equation}

Are $X_{1}^{1}|Y$ and $X_{1}^{2}|Y$ conditionally independent ?

Where can I make use of the i.i.d. property ?

Comment: This seems not true.  Let $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ be iid.  Then couldn't we take $X_1^{1} = X_2$ and $X_1^2 = X_3$ to get $X_1^1, X_1^2$ to be iid as $X_1$, but not independent of $X_2$ and $X_3$?

Comment: All $X_{i}, \ i \in \{1,2,3\}$ are independent from each other **and** not i.i.d. if that information was missing somewhere.

Comment: Okay, so we have the additional information that the distributions of the $X_i$s are unique?

Comment: I don't see a clear question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.  Let $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$, $X_2 \sim N(1,1)$, and $X_3 \sim N(-1,1)$ all be independent, so $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ satisfies the assumptions of the problem.  Observe that $X_1^1 := X_2 - 1$ and $X_1^2 := X_3 + 1$ are both $N(0,1)$ random variables and independent, so are i.i.d. as $X_1$.  However, $(X_1^1 + X_1^2, X_2, X_3) = (X_2 + X_3, X_2, X_3)$ are not independent.

Comment: In my particular case, I consider a data matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n,3}$, where in each row $(X_{1}^{i}, X_{2}^{i},,X_{3}^{i})$ all variables are independent. When would I have independence in a j-th row where $(\sum_{k \neq i} X_{1}^{k}, X_{2}^{j},X_{3}^{j}$ ? Would that hold for some distributions ?

Comment: @Ltastic This certainly holds for *some* random variables.  General conditions to ensure independence is probably more complicated and should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Will do, thank you so much for the feedback!