# Conditions for independence of sum of i.i.d. random variables from remaining

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, convolution, independence

Previously I asked the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733908/independence-of-sum-of-i-i-d-random-variables-from-remaining-variables), that does not generally hold:

The following question is very similar to [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308348/sum-of-independent-random-variables-is-also-independent).

Let $(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})$ be a random vector with continuous independent variable entries. We denote by $X_{1}^{1}, X_{1}^{2}$ two variables that are i.i.d. as $X_{1}$

Claim: $(X_{1}^{1}+ X_{1}^{2},X_{2}, X_{3})$ are again independent.

I would required this for a sum of $n$ i.i.d. variables, which would follow by induction.

Proposed proof:

Let $Z := X_{1}^{1}+ X_{1}^{2}$ and $Y := (X_{2}, X_{3})$.

In similar fashion to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308348/sum-of-independent-random-variables-is-also-independent) we repeat the application of the convolution formula

\begin{equation}
f_{z, y}(z, y) =f_{z \mid y}(z \mid y) \cdot f_{y}(y) 
=f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_0^{z-x_1^2} f_z\left(x_1^1, x_1^2 \mid y\right) d x_1^1 d x_1^2 = f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_z\left(z-x_1^2, x_1^2|y\right)  d x_1^2
\end{equation}

Here comes a step, where one requires that $X_{1}^{1}|Y$ is independent from $X_{1}^{2}| Y$. I am not certain whether this is actually satisfied

\begin{equation}
f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_z\left(z-x_1^2, x_1^2|y\right)  d x_1^2 = f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{x_{1}^{1}} (z-x_1^2|y) f_{x_{1}^{1}} (x_1^2|y) d x_1^2 =f_{y}(y) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{x_{1}^{1}} (z-x_1^2) f_{x_{1}^{1}} (x_1^2) d x_1^2 = f_{y} (y) f_{z} (z)
\end{equation}

Are $X_{1}^{1}|Y$ and $X_{1}^{2}|Y$ conditionally independent ?

Where can I make use of the i.i.d. property ?

The answer was that this statement does [not generally hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4734558/1089486).

I cite the answer:
This is not true.  Let $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$, $X_2 \sim N(1,1)$, and $X_3 \sim N(-1,1)$ all be independent, so $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ satisfies the assumptions of the problem.  Observe that $X_1^1 := X_2 - 1$ and $X_1^2 := X_3 + 1$ are both $N(0,1)$ random variables and independent, so are i.i.d. as $X_1$.  However, $(X_1^1 + X_1^2, X_2, X_3) = (X_2 + X_3, X_2, X_3)$ are not independent.

My question is:

1. What condition would ensure for it to work ?
2. When does it work ? Examples of distributions would help.

Comment: You have assumed $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ has independent entries.  You cannot then say $X_1^1 := X_2 - 1$ and $X_1^2 := X_3 + 1$ without breaking that assumption. (I dislike the superscripts as they look like exponents)

Comment: That I agree on. @Henry without that answer, how would you go about it ?

Comment: You asked the same question twice and got anwer with a counterexample the first time around? Anyway, I think you want to know the following property: if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random objects (e.g. random matrices -matrices with r.v.'s as entries-) and $\varphi, \psi$ are Borel functions, then $\varphi(X)$ and $\psi(Y)$ are also independent. For instance, if $X$ and $Y$ are indeed independent random matrices, so are $\mathrm{tr}\ X$ and $\det Y.$

Comment: What it is not generally true is that $\varphi(X)$ and $\psi(X)$ will be indepedent; however, ocassionally they will be, but if and only if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are evaluated on "independent" parts of $X.$ For example, suppose $X$ is a uniform number on $[0,1]$ and expand it using binary expansion $X = \sum \alpha_i 2^{-i},$ and make this expansion unique by not allowing $\alpha_k = 1$ for all $k \geq i_0.$ Now let $\varphi(X) = a_1$ and $\psi(X) = a_2,$ these random numbers are independent Bernoulli random variables variables.